# In Echarts, how to title/label series (pies) in nested pie chart

Tags: echarts

In Apache Echarts, when using multiple pie charts (e.g. nested pies, or even side-by-side pies), **how do we add a title to each pie to signify what the pie represents**? While the "title" option can accept an array of titles, there isn't a good way to position them so that they are above, within or in some other way related to the respective pies they are meant to label. It's as if there's a missing concept of a seriesLabel / seriesTitle that sits conceptually between the chart title and the individual item labels.

Series *item* labels are already in use for the items (pie slices) so cannot be used with position: center, and that wouldn't help with nested pies anyway since there's only room for one label at the center.

Here are my nested pies. I used an image editor to add labels where I might want them - hugging the pies they each label. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand what is your problem with the array of titles...

Here is a simple example showing how to give a title to each pie:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    value: 15
  }
];

let option = {
  title: [
    {
      text: 'Pie 1',
      subtext: 'Left',
      left: '46px',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    {
      text: 'Pie 2',
      subtext: 'Center',
      left: '146px',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    {
      text: 'Pie 3',
      subtext: 'Right',
      left: '246px',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '42px',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      left: 0,
      right: '66%',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '42px',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      left: '33%',
      right: '33%',
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '42px',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      left: '66%',
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 0
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Same example with nested pies:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    value: 15
  }
];

let option = {
  title: [
    {
      text: 'Pie 1',
      left: '48%',
      textAlign: 'center'
    },
    {
      text: 'Pie 2',
      left: '48%',
      top: '26%',
      textAlign: 'center'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['120px', '90px'],
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      top: '10px'
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '42px',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      top: '10px'
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

If you want something completely responsive with nested pies, indeed, I do not know the recipe using a simple array of titles...

But you can do this somehow creating **two containers**, which means each pie will be in its own `<canvas>` element. Then you can use CSS to give your inner pie an **absolute** position.

There is extra work to handle the behavior of both charts on resize. Your `<canvas>` elements should always be squares. In other words, their width and height should stay equal.

When you resize the window, you have to get its width and height to determine if you have a horizontal display or a vertical one. In both cases, take the smallest value and resize **outer** and **inner** containers (width and height) with it. You can even get a variable font size thanks to this value.

Of course, you should avoid `px` in your options. Prefer `%` instead.

Here is the code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    value: 15
  }
];

let outerOption = {
  title: {
    text: 'Pie 1',
    top: '2%',
    left: '50%',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['100%', '80%'],
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      top: '10%'
    }
  ]
};

let innerOption = {
  title: {
    text: 'Pie 2',
    top: '25%',
    left: '50%',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '50%',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      top: '10%'
    } 
  ]
};

let outerChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('outer')),
    innerChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('inner'));

outerChart.setOption(outerOption);
innerChart.setOption(innerOption);

function resize(container, size) {
  container.resize({
    width: size,
    height: size
  });
  
  container.setOption({
    title: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: Math.round(size / 20)
      }
    }
  });
}

['load', 'resize'].forEach(event => {
  window.addEventListener(event, () => {
    let width = window.innerWidth,
        height = window.innerHeight,
        size = width;

    if (width > height) {
      size = height;
    }

    resize(outerChart, size);
    resize(innerChart, size);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#outer, #inner {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="outer"></div>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

Comment: My pies are nested. The outer pie is a donut (with inner radius > 0) and the inner pie is inside of it.

Comment: OK, no problem. I edited my answer. Is it what you are trying to do?

Comment: In my question I said "While the "title" option can accept an array of titles, there isn't a good way to position them so that they are above, within or in some other way related to the respective pies they are meant to label"... your answer gives me two titles but they are not related to the pies in any way, and I cannot position them to show which pie they are associated with.

Comment: If my inner and outer pies grow or shink responsively with a change in screen realestate, any titles I work with have to move with them. I cannot seem to come up with a math formula that consistently positions them relative to the radius settings of the pies, which I suspect is due to the %s of radii and of the tile top parameter being calculated on different containers.

Comment: "*If my inner and outer pies grow or shink responsively with a change in screen realestate*" What do you mean? The main container with both pies is only 300x300 pixels, so you can display it on mobile phones. Even if you work with dynamic data, why would you want to change radii? Could you share a code snippet to understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: My ECharts code is too complex and spread across several components to share here. My users are employees using Edge or Chrome on workstations, and windows can be resized, maximized, etc.. not to mention how window realestate can be divided among visual components that can be resized. All of which to say, the area for ECharts to work in is unpredictable and it must be responsive. Font sizes change also as real estate diminishes. I've accomplished this by reactively setting opts wherein I multiply pixel units by a multiplier that represents the relative font sizes.

Comment: ... and by using % whenever possible and repainting on resize events. It works fine. What I cannot seem to do is label my inner and outer pies in a way that the label stays put relative to the outer edge of the pie.

Comment: The use case seems very specific here and I think it is quite difficult to help you more on this issue if we keep this level of abstraction.

Comment: I put a picture in my original question that shows what I'm after. Now imagine that the chart resizes every which way. The labels would need to stick with it.

Comment: OK, I see... I edited my answer with a new strategy. What do you think?

Comment: Thank you, that's an acceptable approach. Appreciate the help!